# Windows Update GPO not applying 'Empty' on client computers SBS 2011

Tags: group-policy, windows-sbs-2011

I have a Windows Update Group Policy that is not applying to the Client PCs.

The policy is created in the Domain local policy list under `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Update\`

In `Scope` `Security Filtering` I have the Client PCs added with `Read` permissions.

However, a `gpresult /H <html file>` on the client PCs shows the following, indicating to me that it is not applying.

[image]

Any idea why?

PS. I have applied `gpupdate /force` on the client PCs and still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Empty would indicate that you didn't configure anything in the GPO. Double check the GPO to make sure you've actually configured the settings you're trying to apply and that you've configured them under the appropriate node, either Computer Configuration or User Configuration.